# Display different divs on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to display div="block2" when the user clicks "Yes" and display div="block3" when the user clicks "No".

Question:
1.How do I display both block2 & block3 at the same place where block2 is currently displayed.
2. Block2 needs to be hidden when clicked "No" and Block3 needs to be hidden when clicked "Yes"

```
<div id="block1">
    <input type="submit" value="Yes"/>
    <input type="submit" value="No"/>
</div>

<div id="block2">
    Block2
</div>

<div id="block3">
    Block3
</div>

css

html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
#block1{
    height:10%;
    width:50%;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:green;

}

#block2{
    height:90%;
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:green;
}


#block3{
    height:80%;
    width:50%;
    float: left;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:green;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/zcWJ6/6/

html:

```
<div id="block1" class="box">
    <input id="yes" type="submit" value="Yes"/>
    <input id="no" type="submit" value="No"/>
</div>

<div id="container">

    <div id="block2" class="box">
        Block2
    </div>

    <div id="block3" class="box">
        Block3
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container {
position: relative;
height: 100px;
width: 50%;
}

#block1 {
    height:10%;
    width:50%;
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom: none;
}

#block2{
    background: violet;
    position: absolute;
}

#block3{
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
}

.box {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

js:

```
$('#yes').click(function(){
    $('#block3').hide();
    $('#block2').show();
});

$('#no').click(function(){
    $('#block2').hide()
    $('#block3').show();
});
```

Comment: It works perfectly..Im using 5 divs laid one over another..but the text all look blurred..how can I prevent it happening

Comment: What u mean with blurred?

Comment: I got it fixed...I was showing all the objects on top of everything and thats the reason it was like that..

Answer (score 1):

You can display them in the same place using `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0`. Just set whatever the parent div is, to `position: relative`.

You can use javascript or a library like jQuery to listen for the click, and show the right element.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution that may work for you:

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x8B77/)**

I added added a wrapping container to your content blocks, and tweaked the CSS a tiny bit.

HTML:

```
    <div id="block1">
        <input id="yes" type="submit" value="Yes"/>
        <input id="no" type="submit" value="No"/>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="block2">
            Block2
        </div>

        <div id="block3">
            Block3
        </div>   
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
 //new entries
 .container{
   position: relative;
   height: 300px;
 }
 .hidden {display:none;}
```

*edit* (added a second way to do this using delegation) JS:

```
    $('#yes').on('click', function () {
        $('#block2').toggleClass('hidden');
    });

    $('#no').on('click', function () {
        $('#block3').toggleClass('hidden');
    });

    // OR

    $('#block1').on('click', 'input', function () {
       $('.container').children('div').eq( $(this).index() ).toggleClass('hidden');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make javascript string of div2 and div3 content.

Now add one more div.

```
<div id="displayhere"></div>
```

store your div2 and div3 in javascript string. User Jquery click event. After click event add the div2 content to displaynone html.

```
$("#display2").click(function(){
  $("#displayhere").html("div2 content javascript string");
});
```